# Strange Project and File References in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am receiving the following error when trying to build/run the RSOWeb project. The error does not occur when trying to build or run the RSODesktopApp project.

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> NU1201 Project RSOWebDesktopApp is not compatible with net6.0
> (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0). Project RSOWebDesktopApp supports:
> net6.0-windows7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v6.0) RSOWeb
> C:\Users\jag\VisualStudioProjects\Baptist\MirionBadgeApp\RSOWeb\RSOWeb.csproj
> 1

However, neither project references the other and this error just appeared. Don't recall making any project level changes that would lead to this error. Additionally, I'm seeing lots of strange warning in other projects such as files that should be there are not loaded but do appear in the actual windows folder and files that shouldn't be in there have the dotted lines with an x as if visual studio can't locate the file. It shouldn't because the file isn't part of that project - see image??? The DataAccess etc files aren't part of this particular project but it seems like VS is trying to find them????

[image: Example of files image]

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's official documentation on [NU1201](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1201) explanation, it is because the dependency project does not contain compatibility with the current project s frame. The target framework of RSOWebDesktopApp is .net6.0-windows7.0, which is not compatible with .net6.0. You can change the target OS version of RSOWeb to windows7.0. as follows:

[image]

Or change the target OS version of RSOWebDesktopApp to windows10.0.xxxx

Regarding the icon, it should also be the reason for the reference version conflict. If the above method does not solve your problem, please let me know

Comment: Thank you. I read that description as well. Question: Why would it matter since neither project references the other? I don’t recall seeing this error previously and I know I ran the project a week or so ago.

Comment: Also, RSOWeb is a Blazor web server project. What would be the implications of targeting windows or vice versa with the desktop app targeting just net6.0?

Comment: @physics90 Hi, can you provide a minimal reproducible example? I used two unreferenced projects to change their target os, no matter whether they were started at the same time or started separately, the above situation did not occur